# Expand wedge product

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry, tensors, differential-geometry

How can I force mathematica to expand for example this expression

$$(\cos (\theta ) dr-r d\theta  \sin (\theta ))\wedge (\sin (\theta ) dr+r d\theta  \cos (\theta ))$$

into what is should be, that is

$$r dr\wedge d\theta  \, ?$$

For your convenience:

```
(Cos[θ] Dt[r] - r Dt[θ] Sin[θ])\[Wedge](r Cos[θ] Dt[θ] + Dt[r] Sin[θ])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `Wedge` has no built-in meaning in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Yes, that's the first detail in `Wedge`'s documentation page: "Wedge[x,y,\[Ellipsis]] has no built-in meaning."  `Wedge` is there to allow you define your own favorite wedge product, of which there are many.  `TensorWedge` is a tensorial operation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One idea is to use [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce). I will assume that `r` is real, and that `Dt[r]` and `Dt[θ]` are symbolic vectors:

```
$Assumptions = r ∈ Reals && (Dt[r]|Dt[θ]) ∈ Vectors[{d}];
```

Then, we can use [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify) + [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce):

```
Simplify @ TensorReduce[
    TensorWedge[Cos[θ] Dt[r]-r Dt[θ] Sin[θ], r Cos[θ] Dt[θ]+Dt[r] Sin[θ]]
]
```

> ```
> r Dt[r] \[TensorWedge] Dt[θ]
> ```