# What is the best source to learn how to use tensor operations (exterior algebra) in Mathematica?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, differential-geometry

I'm specifically interested in the TensorProduct,TensorWedge, HodgeDual and certain build in functions to do tensor arithmetic like TensorReduce, TensorExpand.

I would like to do exterior algebra calculations where I can choose to work with basis vectors as symbolic objects (and where I can choose to work without basis vectors).

To be explicit, I would like mathematica to do this
input:

```
v = {v1, v2}; w = {w1, w2};
v\[TensorWedge]w
```

desired output:

```
(v1 w2 - v2 v1) e1 \[TensorWedge] e2
```

actual output (in normal form):

```
{{0, -v2 w1 + v1 w2}, {v2 w1 - v1 w2, 0}}
```

If this is not possible what source gives the best advice on how to use mathematica to deal with exterior algebra related differential geometry topics ? A simple example code,  video, guide or tutorial on the wolfram site would be optimal.

Comment: I‘d also be interested in this! Good question

Comment: For operations with basis elements your can try to look at my geometric algebra package https://github.com/ArturasAcus/GeometricAlgebra . The wedge operation here is implemented as OuterProduct. No operations without basis vectors, no differentiation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the posts under the tag [tensors](/questions/tagged/tensors) isn't a bad choice to learn tensor operation in *Mathematica*. Your specific problem can be solved as follows:

```
Clear[e]
$Assumptions = {v1, v2, w1, w2} ∈ Reals;
e[i_]\[TensorWedge]e[i_] ^= 0;
e[i_]\[TensorWedge]e[j_] /; ! OrderedQ@{i, j} ^:= 
 Signature@{i, j} e[#]\[TensorWedge]e[#2] & @@ Sort@{i, j}

v = v1 e@1 + v2 e@2; w = w1 e@1 + w2 e@2;
Simplify@TensorExpand[v\[TensorWedge]w]
(* (-v2 w1 + v1 w2) e[1]\[TensorWedge]e[2] *)
```

The keypoint is to define the orthogonal basis `e[i]`.

Related:

[Expand wedge product](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/157011/1871)

[Derivative of real antisymmetric matrix in mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/226082/1871)

[how to define unit vectors in mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/245815/1871)

There should be more.

Answer (score 1):

See also John Browne's [Grassmann Algebra](https://sites.google.com/site/grassmannalgebra/) website.